# Keep store up to date in all computers

Tags: extjs

So i am implementing a Chat and I need a feature that will show when the message was read or received by the destination user.

When a message is sent, it is sent over a websocket and there I can update the field to say that the message were received by the destination user, save it on the store and on database.

I have a field in the store to say the message was received by that user, but my problem is, how can I update the store in the sender computer? My store is `autoSync: true` and i don't want to force a force a store.load() every x seconds to see if the record had change.

How can I update this store in every computers?

Comment: The automated response message you want to send ("I have received/read your message") can and should be transmitted via the same channel that the messages take, just in reverse direction. That's how the read notification in email works (it's a specially crafted email), and that's how delivery notification in SMS works (a specially crafted SMS).

Comment: Hi Alexander. My architecture is not that simples, but maybe is the best way to do it, So i'll make some changes implemented like that, responding by the same websocked.